# Values is undefined for control created on POST event - MVC3 & jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Razor code to render controls,

```
 @if(Model.Employees != null && Model.Employees.Count > 0)
 {
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Employees)  
 }
```

I have separate Employees.cshtml inside EditorTemplates folder to bind list of employees.

And in controller, I am binding the list of employees on POST event, lets say Search Button Click event.

Now when i try to select employee name from textbox on radio button change event. I am getting name as undefined. But i see the value inside the textbox.

I have below simple jQuery select to get value of textbox.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

  var SearchRadio = "input[type='radio'][name='SearchRadio']";  


   $(SearchRadio).change(function (){

    alert($("#EmployeeNameTextBox").val());
   });
  });
```

Note: This problem is only with the controls creating at post event.

Let me know, how to get controls values created at POST event.

Comment: Although you didn't post your EditorFor code, it appears that you are using an ID for each textbox called EmployeeNameTextBox.  You can only have 1 unique ID per DOM.

Can you post the code of your EditorFor?

Comment: Also, is SearchPSAPRadio supposed to be the same as the SearchRadio defined above?

Comment: Actually, I am setting the correct Id using the index number. I am looking for any suggestions that I have to handle any specific conditions for controls created on POST event.

Comment: Actually, I am setting the correct Id using the index number. So in real id will be like this $("EmployeeName_"+index+"_Textbox").

I am looking for any suggestions that I have to handle any specific conditions for controls created on POST event.

Comment: @Scottie, thanks for looking into my issue. I found fix for my problem. Before I was using name attribute to get element values. For some reason, name attribute is not working for controls created at post event. So I have used selector on Id. This works fine for me.

In my above example, i showed selector on textbox but in real i am using radio button list. So I was using name attribute to get the checked radio button text.